# Unable to drag control to form

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, libreoffice-writer

I am trying to create a PDF form in LibreOffice Writer and I am unable to add any Controls.
I have `Form > Design Mode` and `Form > Open in Design Mode` checked. I have the Form Controls toolbar displayed and the controls are enabled. Then I try to drag the checkbox, for example, to the form and nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Don't drag from the checkbox tool icon to the form. Instead, click the checkbox tool icon to activate it, and then on the form, drag a rectangle to create a checkbox.

Comment: Thanks. Make this the answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not drag from the checkbox tool icon to the form. Instead, click the checkbox tool icon to activate it, and then on the form, drag a rectangle to create a checkbox.